# How do I double up all values of database in every cell?

Tags: windows-7

I have copied some data into Excel 2007. I have found that I need to double up all the numbers in every cell. For example: {22, 44, 66} become {44, 88, 132}. What is the easiest way to do this? Its a lot..!

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of how your sheet looks like?

Answer (score 0):

Put a relative formula multiplying the cell by 2 in, say, the cell next to each. Then copy all the formulas and paste special the values over the original cells.

Answer (score 0):

1. Put the value 2 in a cell and copy it to the clipboard.
2. Select the cells with the values you want to double.
3. Paste Special and select Multiply
4. Optional: Delete the cell containing the 2.

[image]